# Why does "Enter parameter value" appears using INSERT INTO VALUES?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm always getting the "enter parameter value error" when I try to run this code. The error refers to idPat, idSP, idPar and measure_value.
I have checked with the debug idPar, idPat, idSP and measure_value and they assume the correct value; the errors comes out when I run sql.

```
     Dim idPar As Integer
     Dim idPat As Integer
     Dim idSP As Integer
     Dim current_fc As String
     Dim namePar As String
     Dim sql As String
     Dim measureValue As Integer
    
    current_fc = TempVars!CurrentUsername
    namePar = Me.cmbManualDailyPar.Value
    measureValue = Me.txtMeasureValue

    idPar = Nz(DLookup("ID_par", "Parameter", "name_par = '" & namePar & "'"), 0)
    idPat = Nz(DLookup("ID_patient", "Patient", "fiscal_code = '" & current_fc & "'"), 0)
    idSP = Nz(DLookup("ID_SP", "Diagnosis", "ID_patient = " & idPat & ""), 0)

    
    sql = "INSERT INTO Measure(ID_par, measure_value,ID_SP,ID_patient)" & _
            " VALUES(idPar,measureValue,idSP,idPat);"
            
    DoCmd.RunSQL sql
```

Comment: `idPat` is not yet defined when assigning to `idSP`. Did you mean `idPar`?

Comment: No, my mistake I have edited it but getting still the same error

Comment: The error we are discussing is not related to this error.

Comment: @Lea . . . Print out the SQL and see if it run directly in MS Access.  Start debugging it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `VALUES` part is just text. What you need is:

```
" VALUES(" & idPar & "," & measureValue & "," & idSP & "," & idPat & ")"
```

You may also need to enclose text values in database quotes, for example:

```
" VALUES(" & idPar & ", '" & measureValue & "'," & idSP & "," & idPat & ")"
```

to enclose `measureValue` if it is text.

Comment: The problem is that I want to add integer types, is it possible with VALUES?

Comment: Yes, as shown above. If `idSP` is an integer, its value will be inserted in the text of the `VALUES`.

Comment: Try it, and use the debugger to inspect `sql` before the `DoCmd`

Comment: Before I have tried what you are suggesting me but as I was expected I cannot append rows because the fields in the table are integer type and not string ones

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. How can I do the inspection?

Comment: Inspect means looking at the variable in the debugger. You can also insert a statement before the `DoCmd` `Debug.Print sql` which will print the string to the debug output window of VBA. To start debugging, press the Step Into (F8) button with the cursor in the Sub or Function.

Comment: the Debug.Print sql result is: ''' INSERT INTO Measure(ID_par, measure_value,ID_SP,ID_patient) VALUES(5,100 ,1,1); '''  that is correct. Then I get another error but no more on this subject, thank you!

Comment: That looks correct and should work. But if a row already exists with this primary key, then the insert will fail. What is the primary key of the table?

Comment: As you said, the problem is on the primary key and I have solved. Thank you very much for you help! Have a nice day :)